# How can I use Java upload a folder to AWS S3?

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I checked the document and the code examples. However, I just found the way to upload a file. If I set the file path be a folder， the program would return exception:

`Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to calculate MD5 hash: /path/to/folder (Is a directory)`

I noticed that C# code example has a way to upload folder, but Java doesn't. Does it mean Java cannot upload folder to AWS S3?

Comment: Can you post your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Amazon S3 API only supports uploading one object per API call. There is no API call to upload a folder.

Your code would need to loop through each file in the folder and upload them individually.

Comment: Can I compress a folder, upload it, and decompress it on AWS S3 Server?

Comment: No. Amazon S3 does not have the ability to compress/decompress (eg zip/unzip) files. It is primarily a storage service, but it has been adding features over time (eg selecting data from files, triggering notifications when files are uploaded).